# WCF, Linq-to-SQL and Parameterized Constructors

Tags: sql, linq, wcf, linq-to-sql, constructor

How can I get WCF to allow the following?

```
Dim EmployeeID as Integer = 10
Dim emp As New WcfServiceLibrary1.Employee(EmployeeID)
Response.write (emp.LastName)
```

Currently I have to do this because I can't figure out a way for WCF to allow for Parameterized Constructors:

```
Dim EmployeeID as Integer = 10
Dim emp As New WcfServiceLibrary1.Employee()
emp = emp.GetEmployee(EmployeeID)
Response.write (emp.LastName)
```

It just seems weird that I would have to take this extra step.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I just see you want a constructor to return a value, which can never be the case in OO world. Do you mean something like static methods?

Comment: In a normal class you can overload the contructor like Public Sub New(ByVal EmployeeID as Integer)...  I don't see a way to do this with WCF

Comment: you are using a constructor to create an instance of a service class which is different from a normal class, Also, here WCF is handling object marshaling. you wont be able to do what you are trying to achieve using a service contract.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're calling a method on an object that you retrieve from a WCF service in the first place.  Usually with WCF you call methods on a service contract.  Is Employee a service contract?  Please show us your service contract and data contracts.  Thanks.

Comment: @Perpetualcoder - please put your second comment in as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using a constructor to create an instance of a service class which is different from a normal class, Also, here WCF is handling object marshaling. you wont be able to do what you are trying to achieve using a service contract.